I'm trying to create a Docker composition that automates Let's Encrypt certificates and renewal
I have a webapp that uses React/nginx for the frontend and Node.js for the backend. I want to create a Docker composition that not only spins up the frontend and backend but also takes cares of the TLS certificates. I ran my docker-compose.yaml one many times and now certbot says that I've exceeded the rate limit for requesting a certificate. However, I'm able to run certbot commands on my host machine without any issues. I don't understand why the Docker container has this issue.
Certbot Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9 AS certbot_installer

RUN pip install certbot

FROM certbot_installer AS certbot_runner

CMD ["sh", "-c", "certbot certonly --standalone --agree-tos --email email.com -d domain.net && trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 24h; done"]

Node.js Dockerfile:
FROM node:alpine as build

WORKDIR /node

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

COPY . .

CMD npm start

React Dockerfile:
FROM node:alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/site/client/build

COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www/site/client/build

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD nginx -g "daemon off;"

docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  certbot:
    build: 
      context: ./certbot
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - certbot
    build: 
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  backend:
    depends_on: 
      - certbot
    build: 
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network  
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

